# Woocommerce share catelogue of products on another website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to share my products listed on www.websiteA.com on a page on www.websiteB.com ?

I can add an iframe on websiteb.com but I'd rather have the products copied from websiteA and appear as if they are a part of websiteB.

I need the sale to go to websiteA, even though they are listed on websiteB.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you wanting to be able to purchase the products on websiteB? or will it just be a catalogue / information?

Comment: just the catalogue/info.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this was with an iframe plugin for wordpress.